# How to share usb printer over wireless network?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, printer, network-printer

I have two computers and one printer in room A which are connected to internet over WiFi router which is in room B. There is no way to connect computers or printer over cable to router, only WiFi.

Is it possible some how to share printer over WIFI network? This two computers are sometime both turned on and sometime only one, there is no rule which computer will be turned on.

Os: OSX

Printer: Epson Office BX305F

Comment: You really need to ask a single question. Since product suggestions are off topic anyway, the last question should be removed. Sharing printers is a common task with a lot of resources available on the Internet. Please take a minute tell us what you have researched and attempted so far. Lastly, for anyone to help you, it will be important to know what OS you are using and the make/model of printer.

Comment: @CharlieRB - added extra info

Comment: A print server something like http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/B000LSZ0Q0/ctrlqorg-20/

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a wireless print server. This device plugs into the USB port of your printer and converts the signals to allow for communication across your wifi network. There are several stores that sell these devices, but I think your best luck is to search on Amazon or newegg as these normally aren't carried in store.

Currently they are selling for 50-80 bucks. You will likely need to install all manufacturer software to get things working and may have to disconnect from your wireless router temporarily to connect to the wireless print server to print your document. Then switch back once your done printing. Each manufacture has different ways of handling the printing process so be sure to check reviews and vendor documentation before buying.

Comment: Before you buy a printserver, make sure you check its "printer compatibility list". Especially with low-cost GDI printers like the Epson, if it's not in the list, it won't work. And, if the manufacturer does not offer a list, stay well away from it.